# Sum of the outcomes of a die until three 6s appear

Tags: probability

So the question asks:

Jim is rolling a fair die repeatedly. He records the sum of the outcomes of the die, until the third time the die shows the numbers 6. Denote by S the sum of the outcomes. Example: If he rolls $1, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 6$, then he stops after he rolls the last 6, and $S = 30$. Find $E [S].$

So so far I have: first find the probability that the third time a $6$ appears occurs on the $n$th roll.

I think this is the probability that the $n$th roll is a $6$ and exactly two rolls before it are also $6$'s, so $p=\frac{{n-1 \choose 2}*5^{n-3}}{6^n}$

But I am stuck on calculating the expected value of the sum of the outcomes when the third 6 appears, so how I am supposed to do this? Do I use the mean value of the other five faces, which is $\frac{1+2+3+4+5}{5} = 3$ to calculate the sum of the outcomes?

Comment: Yes, that is what you are supposed to do.  But I suspect there are more problems you'll run into as you try to calculate the expected value. (e.g. since n can be arbitrarily large).
p.s., I believe p = () / 6^3, not just () / 6.

Comment: $3\cdot(1+\dots+6)=63$. $6$ will appear exactly $3$ times and other outcomes expected $3$ times.

Comment: Let $N$ be the number of rolls until stop. Note that $ S = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where $X_i$ is the number of the $i$-th roll. After you obtained the negative binomial pmf of $N$, you can now use the double expectation formula, or so called Wald's equation to calculate the expectation of this random sum.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_k$ be the result of the $k$-th roll.   $$\mathsf E(X_k\mid X_k\neq 6) = 3$$

Let $N$ be the number of rolls until the first six; a geometrically distributed random variable.   $N\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(1/6)$
$$\mathsf E(N) = 6$$

Let $S_N$ be the sum of the results of $N$ rolls where 6 only shows up on the last roll.    Linearity of Expectation says:

$$\mathsf E(S_N\mid N) = 6+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\mathsf E(X_k\mid X_k\neq 6)$$

The Law of Iterated Expectation says: $$\mathsf E(S_N) = \mathsf E( \mathsf E(S_N\mid N))$$

You want the sum of results until the third six shows up.   Use the Linearity of expectation to assert this is $3\mathsf E(S_N)$

Put it all together.